# C# Add Selected Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2 and on the contrary

Tags: c#, winforms

What's Wrong with this?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupBox1.Text))
        {
            lst2.Items.Add(lst1.SelectedItems);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens?  Does it not compile, does it produce an error, is the output different than expected, or what?  We need *details*.  How exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: @Servy this would throw a compiler error, `Items.Add` wants a single `Item`.

Comment: @Evanlewis Yes, but I want the person asking the question to take the time to explain their problem.  It is *their* responsibility to include that information in the question.  That I figured it out on my own within a few seconds doesn't mean he shouldn't have included it to begin with.

Comment: @Servy I agree completely, I'm trying to teach through discussion ;)  If SO was full of only posted code with the comment "What's Wrong with This" we would all be in a world of hurt...

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to add an entire collection of items as a single item in the other collection.

The simplest way to add each selected item appropriately would be to iterate over them and add  them individually:

```
foreach(var i in lst1.SelectedItems)
{
    lst2.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Nevermind. Removed my downvote. +1

Answer (score 0):

Or if you just want to add a single item do:

```
lst2.Items.Add(lst1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your code with this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupBox1.Text))
    {
        lst2.Items.AddRange(lst1.SelectedItems);
    }
 }
```